# Call static function of specialize template with base class of type T

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write Stream class with a template Write function to accept any type and write it to stream.

I write a Stream class and a StreamWriter to partially specialize Write function, but compiler can't find static function of StreamWriter with base class of AInt class.

```
template<typename T>
class AType {
public:
   T rawValue;
    void Add(T v) { rawValue += v; }
    void Sub(T v) { rawValue += v; }
    void Mul(T v) { rawValue *= v; }
    void Mod(T v) { rawValue %= v; }
};

class AInt : public AType<int> {
public:
    using AType<int>::Add;
    using AType<int>::Sub;
    using AType<int>::Mul;
    using AType<int>::Mod;
};

class AFloat : public AType<float> {
public:
    using AType<float>::Add;
    using AType<float>::Sub;
    using AType<float>::Mul;
};
class AStream;

template<typename T>
class AStreamWriter {
public:
    static bool Write(AStream *stream, T v);
};

class AStream {
public:
    template<typename T>
    bool Write(T v) {
        return AStreamWriter<T>::Write(this, v);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class AStreamWriter<AType<T>> {
public:
    static bool Write(AStream *stream, AType<T> v) {
        //Do somethings
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    AInt x{10};
    AStream stream;
    stream.Write(x); //Error, Compiler can't find AStreamWriter<AInt>::Write
}
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Works fine with all current major compilers: https://r.godbolt.org/z/1vc5jnzPa which compiler are you using?

Comment: Not working for me also I'm using MSVC

Comment: Please include the complete error message in the question

Comment: My editor complains that `static bool Write(AStream *stream, T v);` in class `class AStreamWriter` is not implemented.

Comment: @ecatmur i'm using msvc & mingw g++

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number LINK: command ... following output:
DepRes.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl AStreamWriter<class AInt>::Write(class AStream *,class AInt)" (?Write@?$AStreamWriter@VAInt@@@@SA_NPEAVAStream@@VAInt@@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl AStream::Write<class AInt>(class AInt)" (??$Write@VAInt@@@AStream@@QEAA_NVAInt@@@Z)
DepRes.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Compiler search for AStreamWriter<AInt>::Write(AStream*, AInt) and can't resolve it by AStreamWriter<AType<T>>::Write(AStream*, AType<T>)

Comment: put errors in question not comments

Comment: `using AType<float>::Add;` is unneeded (problematic `AType<float>::Mod` might also be instantiated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with c++ concept.
IsAType is a concept that accepts all subclasses of AType.

```
template<typename T>
class AType {
public:
    using RawType = T;
    T rawValue;

    void Add(T v) { rawValue += v; }

    void Sub(T v) { rawValue += v; }

    void Mul(T v) { rawValue *= v; }

    void Mod(T v) { rawValue %= v; }
};

template<typename T>
concept IsAType = std::is_base_of_v<AType<typename T::RawType>, T>;

class AInt : public AType<int> {
public:
    using AType<int>::Add;
    using AType<int>::Sub;
    using AType<int>::Mul;
    using AType<int>::Mod;
};

class AFloat : public AType<float> {
public:
    using AType<float>::Add;
    using AType<float>::Sub;
    using AType<float>::Mul;
};

class AStream;

template<typename T>
class AStreamWriter {
public:
    static bool Write(AStream *stream, T v);
};

class AStream {
public:
    template<typename T>
    bool Write(T v) {
        return AStreamWriter<T>::Write(this, v);
    }
};

template<IsAType T>
class AStreamWriter<T> {
public:
    static bool Write(AStream *stream, T v) {
        //Do somethings
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    AInt x{10};
    AStream stream;
    stream.Write(x);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it needs a c++20 compliant compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your specialization `AStreamWriter<AType<T>>` is unrelated to `AStreamWriter<AInt>` (and you call `AStreamWriter<AInt>::Write(AStream*, AInt)`, not `AStreamWriter<AType<int>>::Write(AStream*, AType<int>)`).

overload or simple template function might be a alternative...

```
template<typename T>
static bool Write(const AType<T>&) { return true; }
```